# Matplotlib plots different color for the same category (bug?)

Tags: python, matplotlib

This piece of code drives me crazy.

Can someone please explain why the third category has 3 different colors (yellow, green and purple) when they should all have the same color?

I have tried all the posibilities but it always returns the same thing.

What is wrong with the code?

```
#----------------------------------------
# get the data
PATH = '/kaggle/input/the-50-plot-challenge/mpg_ggplot2.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(PATH)
gb_df = df.groupby(["cty", "hwy"]).size().reset_index(name = "counts")
gb_df.sort_values(["cty", "hwy", "counts"], ascending = True, inplace = True)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
colors = {i:np.random.rand(3,) for i in sorted(list(gb_df["cty"].unique()))}

for x in sorted(list(gb_df["cty"].unique())):

    x_values = gb_df[gb_df["cty"] == x]["cty"]
    y_values = gb_df[gb_df["cty"] == x]["hwy"]
    size = gb_df[gb_df["cty"] == x]["counts"]
    color = colors[x]

    ax.scatter(x_values, y_values, s = size*10, c = color)

    ax.set_title("Count plot")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using an old version of matplotlib, as I get the following warning (matplotlib 3.1.3):

> 'c' argument looks like a single numeric RGB or RGBA sequence, which
>   should be avoided as value-mapping will have precedence in case its
>   length matches with 'x' & 'y'.  Please use a 2-D array with a single
>   row if you really want to specify the same RGB or RGBA value for all
>   points.

Which is exactly what is happening in your case. The solution is simply:

```
ax.scatter(x_values, y_values, s = size*10, c = [color])
```

Also, you should change the random colors to be within 0 and 1:

```
colors = {i:np.random.random(3,) for i in ...}
```

In detail, since the third category has the same number of items (three) as the color, matplotlib will use the colormap (viridis by default) to map the value to a color. Indeed, if you check the [viridis](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) colormap, you will see that it seems to contain those three colors.

Comment: Hello @blackbear. Thanks for the response. It didn't work but at least I got the idea why it's not working. Anyway, I made a workaround and transforming everything into hex colors using this line: color = matplotlib.colors.rgb2hex(colors[x]). Now it's okay. Thanks again. Huge help!

Comment: Glad you got it working. If my answer was helpful you could still accept it :)

Comment: @NicoP. the gray tick below the score. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Ok, now I see it. Thanks again and sorry :)